# Ng-click does not work first time - but works afterwards

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework, angularjs-controller

I have two states/views called bookmark and bookmarked.
The bookmark view has a button which passes an url into a function called setURL. This function sets the src for the iframe on the bookmarked view.

```
<ion-view view-title="Bookmarks">
    <ion-content>
        <button class="button" ui-sref="myLearning.bookmarked" ng-click="setURL('SOMEURL')">Bookmark</button>
    </ion-content>
    <div class="bar bar-footer bar-assertive"></div>
</ion-view>
```

The bookmarked view has an iframe whose src is set by the button on the previous view. The src is currently set to nothing because I would never navigate to this view unless I've clicked the bookmark button which would pass in an url.

```
<ion-view view-title="Bookmarked">
    <ion-content>
        <iframe id="learningFrame" src="" width="100%" height="100%" seamless></iframe>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

When I run the app and navigate to the bookmark view and click on the bookmark button, it navigates to the bookmarked view but it displays a blank page in the iframe (src="") rather than using the url passed in from the function. However, from this blank page if I navigate to the bookmarks view and click on the bookmark button the second time, the actual url loads.

Why does it the view not use the url that I have passed in through setURL, on the first load?

This is what the function looks like:

```
.controller('bookmarkCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.setURL = function(currURL){
        document.getElementById('learningFrame').src = currURL;
    };
});
```

I don't know why it does not work the first time...
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It is difficult to comment what the actual issue is with the code you have provided. A fiddle would be more helpful

Comment: also avoid touching DOM in controller instead use directives

Comment: Maybe you can try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/nuysbw8o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing DOM manipulation from the controller you could simply use `ng-src` that would have `{{}}` to have decide `src` attribute value.

**Markup**

```
<ion-view view-title="Bookmarked">
    <ion-content>
        <iframe id="learningFrame" ng-src="{{learningFrameUrl}}" width="100%" height="100%" seamless></iframe>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('bookmarkCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.setURL = function(currURL){
        $scope.learningFrameUrl = currURL;
    };
});
```

**Update**

As you wanted to share data between you controllers then you could use service/factory component. Then you can use that service by injecting it inside your controller/directive wherever you wanted to use it.

**Service**

```
app.service('dataService', function(){
   this.learningFrame = {
      Url: ''
   };
   //..other stuff here..//
});
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('bookmarkCtrl', function($scope, dataService){
    $scope.setURL = function(currURL){
        //this can be available in other controller
        //wherever you take value from learningFrameUrl
        $scope.learningFrame = dataService.learningFrame;
        dataService.learningFrame.Url = currURL; 
    };
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it works when the button which calls "setURL" and the iframe are in the same view, but when they are on different views, despite both sharing the same controller, the iframe src is not set to the value of {{learningFrameUrl}}.  While searching for help with this, I found: **"Controllers are disposed when changing routes. This is good behavior since you should not rely on controllers to carry data between views. It's best to create a service to handle that data."**  I'm not sure how I could write a service for this, could you provide me some guidance? Thank you for your help!